# meaning of 'under the fedora'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

"**It's under the fedora.** Wanta run down and look at it with me?"
A police asks his private detective friend to come along to the murder site to take a look.

(from 'Killer in the rain' by Raymond Chandler)

The 'under the fedora' means 'within one's jurisdiction'?
It doesn't sound very common expression in English, so I can't find any similar usage
in any other sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the story, the immediately preceding line is "I ain't told Dravec yet." This gives a hint about the meaning of "It's under the fedora." A fedora is a kind of hat, so this is a reference to the common expression *keeping something under one's hat*, that is, keeping it a secret. The Free Dictionary has some examples of usage of [this expression](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+under+hat).

*Under the fedora* is not a common variant of the expression. I believe this is supposed to be clever wordplay on the part of the character.

Comment: "I believe this is supposed to be clever wordplay". Worthy of the Dowager Countess of Grantham herself. :)

Comment: +1, but I think you're unfair to Chandler. It is the *character* who intends it to be clever wordplay!

Comment: And the character in question does indeed wear a fedora.